# Multi-threading Outlook Application.ItemSend event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook add-in which hooks into the `Application.ItemSend` event in order to make some changes to the email before it is sent. Specifically it adds/removes some attachments depending on the email content.

This post-processing involves going off to the internet, some calculation and possibly some interaction with the user. The user could even cancel the process so we may need to cancel the send altogether by setting the `Cancel` argument to the ItemSend event handler to `true`.

The problem is that, while this is generally quick, it *could* take a while - during which Outlook freezes entirely.

So, how can I do this in a separate thread whilst still maintaining the right to cancel the send? It seems that the only way to delay the send is to actually hold up the entire message thread, which seems ... odd.

Code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.ItemSend+=OnItemSend;
}

private void OnItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mail=Item as Outlook.MailItem;
    if (mail!=null)
    {
        Outlook.Attachments atts=mail.Attachments;

        /* ...lengthy processing on 'atts', during which Outlook is frozen... */

        Cancel=/* result of lengthy processing */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cancel the submission, save the message, read its entry id. Start a separate thread to do the processing (do not touch the OOM in that thread!). When the secondary thread finishes, run on the main thread code that will reopen the item by its entry id and modify the attachments, send the message again. ItemSend even will fire again, but you can ignore it this time (custom property or flag?).

UPDATE (2019) - keep in mind that Outlook 2016 or newer raises an exception as soon as it detects access on a secondary thread. If you need to touch OOM, you can only do that on the main thread in your addin. If you need to access any Outlook data on the secondary thread, you can only use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author - the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object can be accessed on a secondary thread: save the value of the `Namespace.MAPIOBJECT` property in a dedicated variable, then on a secondary thread create a new instance of `RDOSession` - that will initialize the MAPI system on that thread - and set the `RDOSession.MAPIOBJECT` property to the value saved on the secondary thread).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Trying it out now... will let you know!

Comment: How do you get a handle on the main thread so that you can ask it to run code? In a normal .NET environment I would do this using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` but that doesn't seem to be available here...

Comment: If you are using BackgroundWorker, you can use the RunWorkerCompleted event. You can also use a global flag - set it when your thread proc is done, then run a timer on the main thread (use the one from the Forms namespace) and check that flag periodically.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko you're obviously very knowledgeable in this area and I also recall others like Ken Slovak saying not to access the OOM on a diff thread but I just found some information on MSDN that claims otherwise: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sesy69e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . Apparently if you access the OOM on a thread that is created as Single threaded apartment it can work. In my case my long running option needs to access the OOM and there's no other way around it.  I was getting a Context Disconnected message in the debugger and Outlook and my addin was freezing.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko what I did to fix it was to set my thread to STA and also stop updating my progress bar (The addin had a Windows Form with a progress bar that the thread would periodically update) and the freezing seems to have gone away.  Only time will tell for sure.

Comment: The article deals with out-of-proc access (all Office objects are out-of-proc since they are implemented by exes). The problems arise when your code is running *inside* an Office app. That happens if your code is a COM addin or a VBA script (which does not handle threads natively). The latest version of Outlook (2013) will raise an error outright when it detects a call on a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : So are you saying you can access the OOM from a background thread if you're A.)using VSTO and using the Globals.ThisAddIn.Application reference AND/OR  B.)referencing the PIA in a typical .NET assembly and accessing the OOM by creating a new Outlook.Application object ??    BTW I've been doing the former and I still haven't seen the error with Outlook version 2013

Comment: Although I must add I've been running primarily in Outlook 2013 Cached mode and I think most/all of the OOM accesses have been against the local OST in case that makes a difference.

Comment: No, that is not what I am saying - you can never access Outlook 2013 object on a thread different from the main Outlook UI thread. That applies to any addins and external apps. In an external app, you can access OOM from a secondary thread different from your app's main thread, but the call will be marshaled to the main (UI) Outlook thread anyway.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Thanks this is working great for me, but I have one puzzling issue. I added an Outlook folder that I mailItem.Move() my mail items into while I am background processing. In this case, the attachment size reported is off by about 3600 bytes (varies but always around 3600). The attachment content is the same and correct but the reported size is wrong. If I just mailItem.Save() I do not see this behavior. Is there something I am missing as part of the Move() or do you have any suggestion to clear this up?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko the comments on this blog post ( http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/all-outlook-object-model-calls-run-on-the-main-thread ) claims that in .NET VSTO addin, accessing OOM on a background thread is safe, as the calls are automatically marshalled for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that attachment size is attachment data plus whatever the store provider uses to store the file name, extension and other booking data. It is not equal to the file size.

Comment: That blog is wrong. Especially in Outlook 2013 and higher - Outlook will outright returns an error as soon as it detects that it is being accessed on a separate thread. This is true only for an out-of-proc access when all calls are marshaled to the main Outlook thread.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, yes that is what I was assuming the ~3600 bytes of overhead was. Is there a way to get the actual "content length?" Every property I checked is off by the 3600. Currently I am saving the attachment back to disk and then getting that file size which seems ugly.

Comment: Not in the Outlook Object Model. In Extended MAPi (C++ or Delphi), you could open the PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property as IStream (IAttach::OpenProperty), then call IStream::GetStat to get the stream size.

Answer (score 0):

Using OOM on a background thread is not supported.

Comment: This answer needs a little more details. What is OOM? Where is it documented or described that it cannot be used in the manner you assert?

Comment: As @jdv already mentioned, your answer is unclear and since you making a statement about a feature it would make your answer looking more valid if you could include an official source.
Also suggesting alternatives would help future readers of this thread to know what they should do instead.